# add slideToggle() to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

Probably quite easy but I am new to javascript / jquery. 
In the following jsfiddle I have a menu that opens/closes when clicking the button. 
The menu opens when clicking the button and closes when clicking the button again or clicking a link in the menu. 
The menu should always slide in and out. No matter if you use the button or a link. 
If there is a better way than slideToggle it is of course ok to use this method. 
https://jsfiddle.net/TheBB23/dfnewt4y/1/

```js
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");

var hideLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.mobilemenuitems a');

var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var mobilemenuitems = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (mobilemenuitems.style.display === "block") {
      mobilemenuitems.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      mobilemenuitems.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
var header = document.querySelector(".header");
// On click
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {
  // Toggle class "is-active"
  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
  header.classList.toggle("header--is-active");
  // Do something else, like open/close menu
});

document.onload = document.getElementsByClassName("mobilemenuspace")[0].style.display = "none";

document.getElementsByClassName("mobilemenuspace")[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
 this.style.display = "none";
  hamburger.classList.toggle("is-active");
});
```

```css
/* Responsive (Smartphone) Menu */
@media (max-width: 1000px) {

  .nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #24603c;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 2;
  }



  #BurgerSpace>div>button {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
  }

  #BurgerSpace>div>div {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }

  #BurgerSpace {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-top: -2px;
  }
}

.mobilemenuspace {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background: pink;
}




.hamburger {
  padding: 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-property: opacity, filter;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: visible;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner::after {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner::before {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger:hover .hamburger-inner {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.hamburger-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.hamburger-inner {
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

.hamburger-inner,
.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  width: 40px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: absolute;
  transition-property: transform;
  transition-duration: 0.15s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.hamburger-inner::before,
.hamburger-inner::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
}

.hamburger-inner::before {
  top: -10px;
}

.hamburger-inner::after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  transition-duration: 0.13s;
  transition-delay: 0.13s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::after {
  top: -20px;
  transition: top 0.2s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), opacity 0.1s linear;
}

.hamburger--collapse .hamburger-inner::before {
  transition: top 0.12s 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0.66667, 0.66667, 1), transform 0.13s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19);
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner {
  transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
  transition-delay: 0.22s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::after {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: top 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), opacity 0.1s 0.22s linear;
}

.hamburger--collapse.is-active .hamburger-inner::before {
  top: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: top 0.1s 0.16s cubic-bezier(0.33333, 0, 0.66667, 0.33333), transform 0.13s 0.25s cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1);
}

.header--is-active {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

</div>

<div id="BurgerSpace">
  <div class="header">
    <button class="hamburger hamburger--collapse" type="button">
      <span class="hamburger-box">
        <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
      </span>
    </button>

    <div class="mobilemenuspace">
      <div class="mobilemenuitems">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        <h2> Login</h2>

        <li>
          <a href="#">CLUB</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*vorstand">Vorstand</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*mitgliedsantrag">Mitgliedschaft</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?module=*ueber_uns">Über uns</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*Hockey">HOCKEY</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1.Herren">1. Herren</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*1.Damen">1. Damen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">Jugend <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Jugend">Jugend</a>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MJA">Männliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MJB">Männliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnA">A Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnB">B Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnC">C Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnD">D Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*KnE">E Knaben</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*WJA">Weibliche Jugend A</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*WJB">Weibliche Jugend B</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaA">A Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaB">B Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaC">C Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaD">D Mädchen</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=*MaE">E Mädchen</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Erwachsene">Erwachsene</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Trainingsplan">Trainingsplan</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Schiedsrichter">Schiedsrichter</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Hockey-Links">offizielle Links</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=events_gruppe&id=975">Kalender</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*Tennis">TENNIS</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Herren">HERREN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Damen">DAMEN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Jugend">JUGEND</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Trainer">TRAINER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Schule">TENNISSCHULE</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*_action_events_gruppe_id_976">KALENDER</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=platzbuchung_woche&id=117">PLATZBUCHUNG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=*Tennis-Links">OFFIZIELLE LINKS</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=*UhlenTV">UHLEN.TV</a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=profile">MEIN.HTCU</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_edit">PROFIL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=start_news&cmd=list">ARTIKEL</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_meinerechnungen">Meine Rechnungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_mitgliedsbescheinigung">Meine Mitgliedsbescheinigung</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_teilnahmebescheinigung">Meine Teilnahmebescheinigungen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=profile_interessen">Meine Interessen</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=events_meinetermine">Meine Termine</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_wunschmeine">Meine Support-Anfragen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="?module=admin">ADMIN</a>
          <ul class="menulist">
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="#">KASSE <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?module=kasse">KASSE</a>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_tasks">Startseite</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_beleg">SPESEN</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Belege <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchung&cmd=addmulti">Belegschnellerfassung</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_angebote">Angebote</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_rechnungneu">Neue Rechnung</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=members_beitragaktuell">BEITRÄGE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Rechnungen <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=0">Rechnungen unverschickt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=1">Rechnungen offen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=2">Rechnungen in Bezahlung</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=3">Rechnungen bezahlt</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_buchungen&status=6">Rechnungen alle</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_faellig">Übersichten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_einzug">SEPA-ÜW/Einzug</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Buchführung <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_journal">Journal</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_guv">Gewinn und Verlust</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_bilanzoffenk">Übersichten</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_kontenrahmen">Kontenrahmen</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Barkasse <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_barkasse&konto=1000">Hauptkasse</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel2">
                  <a href="#">Bankkonten <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                  <ul class="menulist">
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_kontouebersicht">(Übersicht)</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="menulevel3">
                      <a class=" " href="?action=kasse_bank&bankkonto=250">Vereinskonto Sparkasse</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_overview">ÜBERBLICK</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_basis">BASISKONFIG</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_optionen">OPTIONEN</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu menulevel1">
              <a href="#">VORLAGEN <span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
              <ul class="menulist">
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_mailtemplates">MAIL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_pdftemplates">PDF</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_static">HTML</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menulevel2">
                  <a class=" " href="?action=admin_antraege">Anträge</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="menulevel1">
              <a class=" " href="?action=admin_wunsch">Support-Anfragen</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a few code improvements and questions:   1) .hamburger class is only one in the whole DOM. You can easily get it by using the query selector and would have save the loop. [Line no 7].  (2) Line no 22-27: You are also adding the click event on the .hamburger class. You could have merged both code block [line - 7 onwards] (not sure why you made 2 different blocks here) . (3) This is suggestion : use ES6 syntaxs

Comment: Well I am completely new to JavaScript and just don’t know how to do it better. I also don t really get what you mean...

Answer (score 0):

Few code improvements you can do:

1) Use *ES6* syntax wherever possible. For example, *let*, *const*, *fat arrow function*.
2) In your DOM there is only one hamburger class. So, instead of using *getElementsByClassName* and looping over that. You can use the *querySelector()*. 
Also, you have taken the hamburger class referenced twice  :

```
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("hamburger");

var hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
```

3) You have defined the click handler logic twice in your code. Both can be merged. 
So, below both code blocks can be merged into the one.

```
coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {...}
hamburger.addEventListener("click", function() {...}
```

4) `document.onload = document.getElementsByClassName("mobilemenuspace")[0].style.display = "none";`

You don't need to do this in JavaScript. In CSS, in the *mobilemenuspace*  class just add `display:none`

5) `document.getElementsByClassName("mobilemenuspace")[0]` Again as there is only 1 mobilemenuspace you want to target you can use `document.querySelector`.

This will help in making your code less in lines and better wrt to the right use of the syntax and methods. For the animation part, you are doing toggling of the classes which are correct. As CSS animations are less expensive then JS animations. What you can look into is having more smoothness while toggling in CSS only.

Thanks,
NS